# Python shortest distance while escaping a binary maze using backtracking

Tags: python, algorithm, maze

Need help with finding shortest distance in a binary maze, which is a list of lists matrix, where 0 is an empty cell and 1 is a wall. The maze has x,y starting coordinates that default to 0,0 and it's end point is always bottom right corner. Shortest distance always includes the starting point (i.e., if there are four steps needed from the starting point, shortest distance will be 5)

I need to be using backtracking algorithm. So far I could come up with a function that determines if there is an escaping path at all. It works well:

```
def is_solution(maze, x=0, y=0):

    n = len(maze)
    m = len(maze[0])

    if x == n - 1 and y == m - 1:
        return True
    
    maze[x][y] = 1
    result = False

    for a, b in [(x - 1, y), (x, y - 1), (x + 1, y), (x, y + 1)]:
        if 0 <= a < n and 0 <= b < m and maze[a][b] == 0:
            result = result or is_solution(maze, a, b)
            
    maze[x][y] = 0
    return result


maze = [
      [0, 0, 1, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0],
      [1, 1, 1, 0]
    ]

is_solution(maze)
```

The above will result to True.

Now I am really struggling with finding the shortest distance. I think it should be relatively easy to update the code above so it showed distance if there is a path and inf if there isn't one. But I got stuck. In the example above shortest distance would be 6 (including the starting point)
I also need to add code to be able to get a list of all shortest distances and coordinates of each step in a list of lists format like [[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]] . In this case there is only one path, but if there were two of distance six, that list would include also the list of second shortest path as well.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried yourself to add distance? What did you do to add backtracking? When would you backtrack? What have you tried to remember the path taken so far? Please try to solve the problem yourself and come to SO to ask for help if you have something you expected to work, but can't figure out why it isn't working. Don't ask SO to write the code for you.

Comment: Backtracking is not an efficient approach for shortest path algorithms. You may want to re-check your requirements - it's likely you've misinterpreted something.

Comment: @Grismar, thanks for meanness as always. Though I wrote half the program already. It checks if the path exists. I have no idea how to proceed further than this, hence asking. I only found BFS algorithms that work. Because apparently from what it follows from the comment above - backtracking is not efficient, so nobody uses it. hence no code examples on Geeks or SO.

Comment: @Johnnysmith it's nothing to do with "meanness" and everything to do with what StackOverflow is for. It's here for people with programming issues, but not just to solve their issues, also to provide a valuable resource for others having similar issues. Your question is really just asking "solve this problem plz", even though it's quite trivial (which is not to say you couldn't find some parts hard). Not just my opinion either, but SO policy: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple change to your code to track shortest path

**Shortest Path**

```
def min_solution(maze, x = 0, y = 0, path = None):
    def try_next(x, y):
        ' Next position we can try '
        return [(a, b) for a, b in [(x - 1, y), (x, y - 1), (x + 1, y), (x, y + 1)] if 0 <= a < n and 0 <= b < m]

    n = len(maze)
    m = len(maze[0])
    
    if path is None:
        path = [(x, y)]         # Init path to current position

    # Reached destionation
    if x == n - 1 and y == m - 1:
        return path
    
    maze[x][y] = 1              # Mark current position so we won't use this cell in recursion
    
    # Recursively find shortest path
    shortest_path = None            
    for a, b in try_next(x, y):
        if not maze[a][b]:
            last_path = min_solution(maze, a, b, path + [(a, b)])  # Solution going to a, b next
            
            if not shortest_path:
                shortest_path = last_path        # Use since haven't found a path yet
            elif last_path and len(last_path) < len(shortest_path):
                shortest_path = last_path       # Use since path is shorter
     
    
    maze[x][y] = 0           # Unmark so we can use this cell
    
    return shortest_path


maze = [
      [0, 0, 1, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0],
      [1, 1, 1, 0]
    ]

t = min_solution(maze)
if t:
    print(f'Shortest path {t} has length {len(t)}')
else:
    print('Path not found')
```

---

Output:

```
Shortest path [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)] has length 6
```

**All Paths**

```
def all_paths(maze, x = 0, y = 0, path = None):
    '''
        All paths through Maze as a generator
    '''
    def try_next(x, y):
        ' Next position we can try '
        return [(a, b) for a, b in [(x - 1, y), (x, y - 1), (x + 1, y), (x, y + 1)] if 0 <= a < n and 0 <= b < m]

    n = len(maze)
    m = len(maze[0])
    
    if path is None:
        path = [(x, y)]

    # Reached destionation
    if x == n - 1 and y == m - 1:
        yield path
    else:
        maze[x][y] = 1              # Mark current position so we won't use this cell in recursion

        # Recursively find  pat          
        for a, b in try_next(x, y):
            if not maze[a][b]:
                yield from all_paths(maze, a, b, path + [(a, b)])  # Solution going to a, b next

        maze[x][y] = 0           # Unmark so we can use this cell
    

maze =  [[0, 0, 0], 
         [1, 0, 0], 
         [1, 1, 0]]

for t in all_paths(maze):
    print(f'path {t} has length {len(t)}')
```

---

Output

```
path [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)] has length 5
path [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)] has length 5
```

Comment: Thank you. it works! thinking ways to expand this as well. assume maze maze = [ [0, 0, 0],  [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0] ]. Is it possible to show all short paths in that list? There are two possible routes, both of len 5.

Comment: @Johnnysmith--it's easy to find all paths.  I've found the best way is to do it as a generator as shown in the answer.  An alternative is to add another argument i.e. solutions, that we append to each time we find another path.

Comment: Great solution, can you explain the run time in O() syntax? Thanks.

Comment: @annie2020--I think the run time is exponential in n*m.  This can be seen when you time k x k maze of all zeros.  The time grows exponentially.  This is True since partial paths are computed many times as part of another path. This can be reduced to O(m*n) using memoization on the function so partial paths are only computed once.

Comment: Great info. Wonder it could apply DFS type algorithm to solve it and be more efficient... Thanks for the analysis.

Comment: @annie2020--DFS has exponential complexity (worst case).

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem is that I can't grasp the concept of recursion. Usually things are easy to do with like list.append() and store the result. but it's impossible without a good logic in recursion...

Comment: Just realize that I can use wrapper function and do whatever the hell I want within that. Super thanks!